# How to do a subquery using the result obtained in the original query?

Tags: sql, db2, subquery

Here is the situation I have..I have to fetch all the associated cases for a given quoteId and this requires a join of 3 tables and I am able to come up with a query for that. Below is the sample : for brevity I have omitted some table name and used only Alias name.

```
SELECT distinct caseTable.CASEID, quoteHdrTable.Case_UID FROM 
caseTable INNER JOIN quoteHdrTable ON
quoteHdrTable.Case_UID = caseTable.Case_UID WHERE quoteHdrTable.QUOTE_ID = '12345'.
```

Now for each CASE_UID that returns back, I also need to display its status from a different table. That has structure below.

```
STATUS_TABLE
CASE_UID         STATUS
------------   -----------
123               Good
234               Bad.
345               {null}
```

In the end I want a result like

```
result
case_ID   case_UID       status
001         123           Good
```

Can we use subquery to do a 2nd SQL using the result(case_UID) from first..please provide pointers or a sample SQL statement.

FYI..using DB2 database

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: Can you perform another inner join with the STATUS_TABLE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct c.CASEID, q.Case_UID, s.status
FROM caseTable c 
INNER JOIN quoteHdrTable q ON q.Case_UID = c.Case_UID
LEFT JOIN StatusTable s ON s.CASE_UID = q.CASE_UID
WHERE quoteHdrTable.QUOTE_ID = '12345'
```

Why not just add another `JOIN`?

Comment: and @Tocco..I tried the join..it works fine if there are some entries matching the same Case_UID in status table..but most of the time there could be no entries for that case_UID in Status Table.

Comment: @Sandeep a left join should also output the rows if there is no matching row in the status table.

Comment: Thanks Marc just realised that and the query works fine as expected..Thank you.

Comment: @marc Correct it where is "LEF" -> "LEFT"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      distinct 
            caseTable.CASEID,
            quoteHdrTable.Case_UID,
            status.STATUS
FROM        caseTable 
INNER JOIN  quoteHdrTable 
ON          quoteHdrTable.Case_UID = caseTable.Case_UID
INNER JOIN  STATUS_TABLE status
ON          quoteHdrTable.Case_UID = status.Case_UID
WHERE       quoteHdrTable.QUOTE_ID = '12345'
```

Comment: @Marc and @Tocco..I tried the join..it works fine if there are some entries matching the same Case_UID..but most of the time there could be no entries for that case_UID in Status Table.